# Primefaces fileupload works only for the first file to be uploaded

Tags: spring, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, web.xml

I am using Primefaces and I have an issue with the fileuploader. The problem is that it works fine with the first file I upload (the fileUploadListener is called and the java method uploads the file), but then if I try to upload another file, the listener is not called anymore and the java method is never triggered. If I refresh the page, I can upload another file but again if I try to upload a second one the same thing happens.

**code within the xhtml file:**

```
<p:tab id="eConsentTabPanel" title="Informed Consent" disabled="#{patientHandlerAction.patientTabsStatus}">
  <h:form id="eConsentForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <h:panelGrid id="eConsentPanelGrid">
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{patientHandlerAction.handleFileUpload}" 
                      mode="advanced"
                      update="messages"
                      multiple="true"
                      auto="true"
                      sizeLimit="20971520"
                      label="Select File"
                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc?x)$/"/>
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>  
     </h:panelGrid>
  </h:form>  
</p:tab>
```

**code within the java bean file:**

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {

   ExternalContext extContext=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
   String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(event.getFile().getFileName());
   File result = new File(extContext.getRealPath("//uploaded//" + filename));

   try {
      FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(result);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[6124];

      int bulk;
      InputStream inputStream = event.getFile().getInputstream();
      while (true) {
         bulk = inputStream.read(buffer);
         if (bulk < 0) {
            break;
         }
         fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bulk);
         fileOutputStream.flush();
      }

      fileOutputStream.close();
      inputStream.close();

      messageTitle = "Message";
      messageBody = "The file" + event.getFile().getFileName() + " was succesfully uploaded!";

      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, messageTitle, messageBody));

   }

   catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();

      messageTitle = "Message";
      messageBody = "The file was not uploaded";

      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, messageTitle, messageBody));
      FacesMessage error = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "The files were not uploaded!", "");
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, error);
   }

}
```

**code within the web.xml file:**

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>
      org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
   </filter-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
      <param-value>/HerEhrUploaded/temp</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
      <param-value>20971520</param-value>
   </init-param>      
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using primefaces 3.3.1 and tomcat 7

Comment: Did you try to update the whole form after the upload and not only messages?

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's not an update issue but rather some problem related to Ajax not working properly. The java method is called by the fileUploadListener only for the first file to be upload, but after that, if I try with a second one it doesn't. ???

Comment: Your handleFileUpload method is definitely working.  Do you have another form tag surrounding your p:tab tag?  What scope is patientHandlerAction?

Comment: I have no other form tag surrounding the p:tab, however I have many p:tabs and inside each of them I use a form. The bean I am using has scope session.
I have overtaken this issue by using an iFrame (p:lightBox) to display the uploadFile which is a page with a single form, and that worked fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

I added :

```
event.getComponent().setTransient(false);
```

Inside file upload listener method,

```
public void handleUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    ....
}
```

It's works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found a solution (more workaround than a solution) here:

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6157

It seems to be a problem with **isTransient()** method in the **FileUpload** component.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found what's wrong but I am not sure of what is causing this issue.
The xhtml page that I use to display the fileUpload component, has many tabs and each tab has it's own h:form. I created a new page that has only one form and the fileUpload component seems to work fine there.